# How to destroy (deallocate) instances of view items loaded from a nib file

Tags: macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nib, memory-management

**Questions:**

- Every time i open a nib, new instances of the items in the nib are
  created, is there a way to destroy (deallocate memory) them ?
- Or is not possible to deallocate those views and will till the end of the application ?

  **Reason for asking:** 
  I have 2 views in separate nib files which need to be loaded and since I am unable to destroy the nib view items even after removing all strong references to the view

**Steps tried (without success):**

- setting the view controller's view outlet to nil
- window controller has a view controller strong property, i have set
  that to nil

**My understanding (based on some testing)**

- When i create the same type of view through code (using alloc) without loading the nib file  (NSBundle loadNibNamed) I am able to destroy the view instance.
- but when the view gets created as a result of loading the nib file, the view stays on though i have removed all strong references to the view

**Pls note:** it is a mac cocoa project and uses *Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)*

**My project details:**

- I have 3 nib files:

  - MyViewA.nib - contains a custom view of the type MyViewA
  - MyViewB.nib - contains a custom view of the type MyViewB
  - MyWindow.nib - contains a NSWindow and a custom view, lets call this
    as viewX for reference
- There is one window controller and one view controller
- MyWindow.nib has 2 buttons, one button to load MyViewA as a subview to viewX and
  the other for MyViewB to be loaded as a subview to viewX
- I am loading the nib files using NSBundle
- When I try to add a new subview to viewX, i remove the already existing subview by using  removeFromSuperView and remove all strong references to the view

I would like nib file items to be removed (destroy memory) after I finish using them but am not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since you loaded the nib manually using NSBundle you need to manually release the view. Since you are using ARC you can't directly call release, however you can cast it to a void * and use CFRelease as follows:

```
CFRelease((__bridge void *)viewToRelease);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!! I have a few questions through. 1) Is it too drastic CFRelease? 2) Is it preferred to use a separate view controller for each view and load the nib as part of the init method ? Presently I am using one view controller for both the views

Comment: Using CFRelease is the Apple recommended why for situations like this  -- see the Resource Programming Guide page 18.

Comment: It took me countless hours to figure this out myself—what a kludge. Apple should add a 'release' method to NSBundle to tell it that you are no longer interested to a resource.